# Yup accept two cases as ip address and hostname

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I would like to validate an input element's value according to two different cases, it can either be an ip address (like 192.168.1.1) or a hostname (like myDomain.com). I am using Yup with Formik in React.

How can I achieve this, what should I write after the following required method?

```
 const ValidationSchema = Yup.object().shape({ 
      hostnameOrIpAddress: Yup.string().required("Ip Address/Hostname is required")
 })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Yup.string().test() and probably some regexp for testing your string match.

Example:

```js
test('is-ip-address-or-hostname', 'Error message', (value, context) => {
  // check your value and return true/false
  return false
}
```